# How to update new column based on the value of existent columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

On my database table `stocks`, I have the columns:

```
stock_id
make
model
buy_rate
tax
other_charges
```

After inserting data into the above table, I have added a new column named `sell_rate` which is at the moment `NULL`.

- **How do I update data in `sell_rate` using `buy_rate` + `tax`  + `other_charges`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
UPDATE stocks
   SET sell_rate = buy_rate + tax + other_charges
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET sell_rate=buy_rate+tax+othercharges;
```

This will update all the rows with appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
UPDATE stocks  
SET sell_rate = (buy_rate + tax + other_charges)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE stocks  
SET sell_rate = buy_rate + tax + other_charges;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update statement as other guys suggested for fill column in records which are already exist.
for fill the column in the future automatically you should set the column as 'Computed Column' by Set:

Table Design -> Computed Column Specification -> Formula to : buy_rate + tax + other_charges

But you should be aware about some considerations like:

-Computed Columns have some restrictions for indexing (in some cases)

-You can't insert or update directly computed columns

Check this [Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information.

Note: another ways are using update Trigger or defining a job which are useful in specific situations